Interpretation of fundamental solution of Laplace's equation in Evans' Partial Differential Equations
First picture below is from 25th page of Evans' Partial Differential Equations. $\Phi(x)$ is the fundamental solution of Laplace's equation, namely
$$
\Delta \Phi=0
$$
Why in the first red line, Evans say $-\Delta \Phi=\delta_0$ ?
I think the Dirac measure is
$$
\delta_0(A)=
\begin{cases}
1  ~~~0\in A\\
0  ~~~x\notin A
\end{cases}
$$
Besides, why calculation of (9) is faulty ?










$\delta_0$ here is a distribution, not a measure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function

@whpowell96  I feel   they're about the same ? Seemly, the Dirac measure and Dirac function are one to one.

The Dirac delta function is the "density function" of the Dirac measure in some generalized sense.

@whpowell96 Thanks, I know a little. Do you have idea about the first red line ?

The meaning of this line is given in the computation directly above it. Convolving $-\Delta_x \Phi$ with $f$ returns $f$, hence $\Delta_x\Phi = \delta_0$ in the sense of distributions. This property is the definition of the delta function in this context
